# Combining gh-pages and wiki in the same branch

Tags: git, github

I have a github project which also has a Github project page (https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages) and Github wiki. Right now, I have two folders, one for the product, and one for the product site and wiki.

In the ../projects/product folder, I work on the features for the product on master and other development branches.

In the ../project/product-sites/ folder, I have the gh-pages branch checked out, with the wiki repo as a submodule (../project/product-sites/wiki/).

Does this structure make sense? Is this a good way to handle the project?

Comment: @TheCodeArtist, do you want to submit that as an answer, so that I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `wiki` repository as a sub-module of a `gh-pages` repository seems quite logical as they both are often updated simultaneously.

However using sub-modules in git has its own "gotchas". Hence it would save you a lot of time and frustration later-on if you were to familiarise yourself with the common pitfalls of using git submodules as described [**here**](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules#Issues-with-Submodules) and [**here**](http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/why-your-company-shouldnt-use-git-submodules/).